# How to use ajax to use post and locate it's url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

What I want to achieve:
I need to use POST method then after success, it will locate to another url of ajax along with the POST data.

**This is what I have done so far:**

```
<script>
$("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
    var ddate = $("#ddate").val();
    var empid= $("#empid").val();
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'../PaySlip/view_payslip.php',
        data:{numnumnum:empid,dateito:ddate},
        success:function(){
            window.location ="../PaySlip/view_payslip.php";
        }
    });
});
```

Problem:
Upon success, the view_payslip cannot gather the POST data that I have transferred. I know what I did was wrong. That is why I'm asking for help to how to get this right.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: a submit button submits a `<form>` which loads a new page - you need to `prevent` this `Default` action somehow

Comment: You are sending the AJAX to the same endpoint where you want to later redirect the user? Use a form instead of AJAX

Comment: If you are using ajax and at the same time trying to refresh the page after an operation it doesn't make use of ajax functionality at all. Just write a function and call it to update the page without server redirection.

Comment: @JaromandaX Thank you. I just used the form method. I was checking if using ajax was possible.

Comment: @Borjante Thank you. Will used form instead of ajax

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to post dynamic form in success callback.
I have also similar requirement in one of my project and for that I have created a method similar to shown below.

In this method you need to pass URL, windows option and params which is your data object, **name** is the window name, if you want to open in same window then instead of opening a new window you can pass **blank** in **name** param and omit the **window.open()** statement. You can modify it as per your requirement.

```
function submitDynamicForm(url, windowoption, name, params)
{
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", "post");
    form.setAttribute("action", url);
    form.setAttribute("target", name);
    for (var key in params) {
        if (params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var input = document.createElement('input');
            input.type = 'hidden';
            input.name = key;
            input.value = params[key];
            form.appendChild(input);
        }
    }
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    window.open("", name, windowoption);
    form.submit();
    document.body.removeChild(form);
}
```

Comment: Hi. thank you also for this. I just created a simple form with POST.  this would be future reference also for those who are experience with my problem.